# IE11 (or Windows 10) changes my user name when logging into SSL sites

Tags: windows-10, https, internet-explorer-11

Since the latest major Windows 10 update (fall 2015), Internet Explorer (version 11.11) has been refusing to log me into SSL-protected (https:) websites without me having to alter the recorded user name.

[image: Screenshot of SSL dialog]

Windows changes my user name to MicrosoftAccount\my.email@address.com, even when the original user ID was a different one. Windows *does* remember the correct password, so all I have to do is change the user name back to the correct one.

Next time, I log into the site, however, the user name is back to the MicrosoftAccount one.

Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE: maybe I should mention that I am using the same name to log into Windows and as user name for the SSL session.

Comment: Really, no one has the answer? Maybe I should add that I upgraded from Windows 7, the home version that came with my Asus laptop. There must be a lot of people out there with the same problem.

Comment: Do you get similar behaviour with Edge?

Comment: @Burgi. Edge doesn't even save the password for me (yes, I did turn on "offer to save passwords")

Comment: And this happens across all `https` sites?